# rails button action connect to helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out for a long time, how to properly use button_ to and button_to_functions. I'm new to rails and see a lot of confusing syntax.

I have created method in the PagesHelper module printString() and want to call it on the button click. Can someone please point out how to do it?

I dont want to jump to new page via controller, i just want to stay on the page and print out the message when butotn click

Thanks a lot!

```
    module PagesHelper
     def printMessage()
            return "this message from Helper"
     end    
    end

   ------------------------------------------------------------------

   this doesnt work
   <%= button_to "Print", "printMessage()" %>
```

Comment: Rails only provides server side functionality, meaning it will need to send data to the server and do a page reload by default. If you want something to happen without a page load, you'll need to add JavaScript.

Comment: I tried adding JS onlcik method, but, it didnt work             <input type="button" value="print" onclick= <%= "printMessage()" %>>

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is tutorial level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Berrlington's comment, you're getting confused between Javascript & Rails. JS provides client-side functionality, which allows you to manipulate things when the [DOM (document object model)](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html) has loaded. Rails is basically a rendering engine for the server, allowing you to use dynamically loaded data to make those pages show

---

**You Need To Use Javascript**

You're trying to dynamically input data into the rendered page by clicking your button

The problem is that Rails cannot change elements on your page when it's already loaded. Rails is not a live processing engine, it takes HTTP requests, and renders "views" based on the request

The way to get your button working is to use [Rails' JS functionality](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) to dynamically load the content, like this:

```
<%= button_to "Create", :action => "print_message", :remote => true %>

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def print_message
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js 
    end
end

#app/views/your_controller/print_message.js
alert('your message');
```

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you need any more help

Comment: That would be great actually! How could I contact you in case, I've got some question?

Comment: rpeck@frontlineutilities.co.uk is my email, or you could just comment on here

Comment: I've created a new file called print_message.js under my views/pages, and I added to routes get "pages/print_message", and post "pages/print_message". However it just gives me a blank page at the end. do you know what could be the problem?thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
module PagesHelper
  def print_message
    "this message from Helper"
  end    
end

<%= button_to_function "Print", "alert('#{print_message}')" %>
```